# Undefined local variable or method with Rails & Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Rails 3.2
Devise
Devise security extensions
```

In my app/views/users/shared/_links.slim, I have:

```
- if devise_mapping.lockable? && resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) && controller_name != 'unlocks'
  li.home-nav= link_to t('users.shared.didnt_received_unlock'), new_unlock_path(resource_name)
```

In my User model, I have:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,  :invitable, :confirmable,
     :password_expirable, :password_archivable, :session_limitable, :expirable, :secure_validatable,
     :lockable, :timeoutable
```

When a user tries to log in, I get the following error:

NameError (undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<#<Class:0x000000098a1598>:0x000000092d4b60>):
  app/views/users/shared/_links.slim:5:in`_app_views_users_shared__links_slim___1531266065579142927_70700660'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:96:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim___452855375923455357_79638440'
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in`call'

Any ideas?

Comment: resource_class is not available in your `_links.slim` view. Use `User.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)` instead

Comment: This worked. I had tried current_user.unlock_strategy_enabled, thinking it would work, but it did not. Please change the comment to an answer, so I can give you credit for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource_class` is only available in the Devise controller, and not in your `_links.slim` view. Use `User.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)` instead